# Parquet file - Timeseries with variable frequency

Tags: time-series, parquet

My situation is:

- I have a list of hundreds of timeseries parameters
- Each parameter is independent of each other
- Each parameter has a basic frequency (lets say, 10hz) but due to hardware limitations may be saved from 9 to 11 hz (variable frequency).
- Each parameter has a different base frequency
- Normally, I only need to read a few of there parameters (columns) at a time and "join them" by the timestamp.

My questions are:

- Do you think parquet would be a suitable file format given this brief description?
- Can parquet deal with variable frequency? In other words, does it save a timestamp associated with each value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parquet itself doesn't timestamp the data, you need to do this yourself, adding an extra field where you will store the timestamp of each individual reading. If you know the frequency with which each parameter has been read, it's trivial to convert to timestamp before inserting the data into the file.

The next problem you'll run into is that parameters will not be read exactly at the same time, so you must account for this in whatever calculations you need to do with your data. At this point you have many different options depending on your needs and the nature of your data, I'll just mention one. For continuous variables, you could resample your data so that the timestamps are the same for every parameter. You can do this by interpolating your readings at the real timestamps to calculate the reading at the target timestamp. There are many mathematical considerations at this point, but they are beyond the scope of your question and the relevance of the storage format.

Answer (score 1):

in short 
1. yes
2. no

I would suggest saving the data in different files per frequency if the difference is greater than 5 meaning one is 5Hz and the other is 10Hz.
Another approach is to fill the gaps with null so the data would like something like this

```
schema = types.StructType([
  types.StructField("timespeed", types.LongType(), False),
  types.StructField("speed", types.LongType(), True),
  types.StructField("tempature", types.LongType(), True)
])

data = [
  (1, 6, 10),
  (2, 7, None),
  (3, None, None),
  (4, 8, 11),
  (5, 9, None)
]

df_w_schema = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df_w_schema.collect()
df_w_schema.write.parquet('nullable_check_w_schema')

df_parquet_w_schema =  sqlContext.read.schema(schema).parquet('nullable_check_w_schema')
df_parquet_w_schema.printSchema()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see that parquet have some concepts like row group, column chunks, page, etc.  Do you think it is possible to use it to increase performance (regarding question 2)

Comment: for your second question, I would break my files by time range and frequency. according to https://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/ the row group, column chunks, and page are features to improve performance and faster reads.